# How to secure REST API (and not the views) with Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've got an application which serves some web content via Spring MVC and also some JSON stuff under the same URI.

```java
@Controller
public class SomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/someUri"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public String getView() {
        return "index.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/someUri", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody String getJson() {
        return "{ \"some\": \"json\" }";
    }
```

And now I want to secure only the REST API which produces the `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` with Spring Security.

When I add the `@PreAuthorize` or `@Secured` annotation on each method it works fine. But I want to configure it globally, like in the `WebSecurityConfiguration#configure(HttpSecurity http)` method. Is it possible to secure in any way globally an endpoint which produces a specific media type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`MediaTypeRequestMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/MediaTypeRequestMatcher.html):

> Allows matching `HttpServletRequest` based upon the `MediaType`'s resolved from a `ContentNegotiationStrategy`. By default, the matching process will perform the following:
>
> - The `ContentNegotiationStrategy` will resolve the `MediaType`'s for the current request
> - Each matchingMediaTypes that was passed into the constructor will be compared against the `MediaType` instances resolved from the `ContentNegotiationStrategy`.
> - If one of the matchingMediaTypes is compatible with one of the resolved `MediaType` returned from the `ContentNegotiationStrategy`, then it returns true
>
> For example, consider the following example
>
> ```
> GET /
> Accept: application/json
> ```
>
> ```java
> ContentNegotiationStrategy negotiationStrategy = new HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy()
> MediaTypeRequestMatcher matcher = new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(negotiationStrategy, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
> assert matcher.matches(request) == true // returns true
> ```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Spring security does not have to do anything with the media type produced by the url. The security constraints are applied to URL patterns. When you talk about @PreAuthorized and @Secured, I assume you are looking for a global authorization mechanism. Yes, you can do something like that

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
    }
    ...
}
```

But it is a good idea to move all of your rest apis that require authorization to some sort of sub domain like /secure/** so that you can apply the security to a single pattern directly. Otherwise, you need to register all patterns one by one.